# Array of structs prints zeros when called, but displays correct input when not called (short code)

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

The purpose of the program is a bank account interface, where the user can create 4 accounts and can transfer funds between them. I opted for an array of structs to handle the “bank account” info, and a switch to handle the user options.

Problem:

The account creation function, called in case ‘a’, appears to create the accounts as intended, and displays them properly. However, the results in the other cases are not as designed.

Case ‘b’ will display the inputted array information, *only* if nothing is called (including the function that displays the array information), otherwise when the display() is called it prints zeros (what it is initialized to before account creation).

Case ‘c’ will display the inputted array information if nothing is called, as well as if only the function which displays the date/time is called. Otherwise it prints zeros.

Question:

Why is the array of structs displaying zeros when I call the display function, but will display the user input when it’s not called, as long as nothing else is (except the time function in case ‘c’), and what can I do to fix it?

Notes:

I converted the account creation function to return a pointer to the struct hoping that might help, it didn’t seem to change anything. I converted the switch statement to a series of if’s to see if that would change anything, it did not (reversed back to switch). Case ‘d’ and case default work as intended. The Program is not complete (my transfer() isn’t written). I’m aware “using namespace std;” is a nono.

I appreciate your time and any advice offered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
const int SIZE = 4;
using namespace std;

struct bank  //Bank Account Structure to hold account numbers and balances
{
     int num; // number of account
     int checkdigit; // ending account number checkdigit appended to account number
     float bal; // balance of account
};

void menu(); //MenuPrompt

bank* input(bank[]); // Struct Account Input
void display(bank[]); // Struct Account Display
void initialize(bank[]); // Struct Account Initialization

char transferprompt(bank s[]); // Transfer Menu

int createaccounts(); //Create Account Numbers and Balances
void time();    //Displays the Current date, month, year, and time.
void clearscreen(); //Prints 40lines to clear the screen

int main()
{
    bank accounts[SIZE]; // Array of bank-account structs
    initialize(accounts); // Removes garbage values
    char select; //User input variable
    bank *ptr;
    ptr = &accounts[0];
    menu(); //Runs MenuPrompt
    cin >> select; //Grabs user input
    select = static_cast<char>( tolower( select ) ); //Ensures user input is lowercase (for switch statement)
    clearscreen();

    switch ( select )
    {
        case 'a': //Creates Accounts
        input(accounts);
        clearscreen();
        main();
        display(accounts);
        break;

        case 'b': //Transfers between accounts
        //display(accounts);
        transferprompt(accounts);
        //main();
        break;

        case 'c': //Displays day, month, year, time, + Account Information.
        time();
        break;

        case 'd': //Exits Program
        break;

        default: //Invalid Input failsafe; Restarts menu prompt.
        cout<<"Invalid selection. Restarting...\n";
        main();
        break;
    }
}
char transferprompt(bank s[])
{
}
bank* input(bank s[]) // Creates Bank Accounts
{
        bank accounts[SIZE]; // Array of bank-account structs
        bank *ptr;           // Pointer to struct
        ptr = &accounts[0];  // Points pointer to array of bank-account structs
    cout << "Account Creation Selected; Create " << SIZE << " accounts..." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Account Number: ";
        cin >> s[i].num;
        s[i].checkdigit = s[i].num % 5;
        cout << "Enter Account Balance: ";
        cin >> s[i].bal;
    }
    return ptr;
}
void display(bank s[]) //Displays Bank Accounts
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Account: " << s[i].num << s[i].checkdigit;
        cout << " has balance: $" << s[i].bal << endl;
    }

}
void initialize(bank s[]) // Removes Garbage values
{
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        s[i].num = 0;
        s[i].checkdigit = 0;
        s[i].bal = 0;
    }
}
void clearscreen() // Clears screen
{
    cout << string(40, '\n');
}
void time() // Display Time function
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    tm* ptr = localtime(&t); // ptr = Pointer to compute time
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Date:  " << (ptr->tm_mon)+1 <<"/"<< (ptr->tm_mday)<< "/" << (ptr->tm_year)+1900 << endl;
    cout << "Time:  " << (ptr->tm_hour) <<":"<< (ptr->tm_min)<< ":" << (ptr->tm_sec) << endl;

}
void menu() // Menu Prompt
{
    cout << "Parkville Bank Client Program; Edit your accounts:\n";
    cout << "a. Create " <<SIZE<<" accounts\n";
    cout << "b. Transfer money from 1 account to another\n";
    cout << "c. Display account balances\n";
    cout << "d. Quit the program\n\n";
}
```

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable in your `input` function.   Your program becomes moot beyond that, since returning a pointer to a local variable is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also, you are calling`main` recursively.  Don't do this, it is not legal C++.   But even if it were legal, what if I were a wise guy and decided to run your program for 100,000 iterations?  Your call stack would look nuts with all of those calls to `main` stacked up on each other.  Use the requisite looping paradigm instead (`for`, `do-while`, etc.)

Comment: "struct bank  //Bank Account Structure" - for the love of god if its a struct represening a bank acount call it "struct BankAccount" not "bank" which looks look a struct representing... a Bank.

Answer (score 1):

This function is not correct:

```
bank* input(bank s[]) // Creates Bank Accounts
{
   bank accounts[SIZE]; // Array of bank-account structs
   bank *ptr;           // Pointer to struct
   ptr = &accounts[0];  // Points pointer to array of bank-account structs
   // ... lines removed ...
   return ptr;  // <-- Undefined behavior
}
```

You are returning a pointer to a local variable / array.  Returning pointers or references to local variables is *undefined behavior*.  The reason why is that since the array is local, once the function returns, it doesn't logically exist anymore.  So you're eventually pointing to an non-existing entity.

What you probably wanted to do is something like this:

```
bank* input(bank* s) // Creates Bank Accounts
{
    cout << "Account Creation Selected; Create " << SIZE << " accounts..." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Account Number: ";
        cin >> s[i].num;
        s[i].checkdigit = s[i].num % 5;
        cout << "Enter Account Balance: ";
        cin >> s[i].bal;
    }
    return &s[0];
}
```

Since `s` was passed in, you probably meant to pass the address of the first element of this entity instead.  Also note that this:

```
bank* input(bank s[]) // Creates Bank Accounts
```

is no different than this:

```
bank* input(bank* s) // Creates Bank Accounts
```

as arrays decay to pointers.

I would really recommend you use containers such as `std::vector` instead of raw arrays and global constants to keep track of the number of entities (for example, `SIZE`).  Then

---

Another issue with your program is that you're recursively calling `main`.  Don't do this, as it is not legal C++.  Instead, use the proper looping constructs such as `while()` and `do-while()`.